# How to create rectangle in html/css?

Tags: css, html, styles, border

How to create this border style?
http://joxi.ru/gmvp74MTxD6lNA

Text with borders, but one side of the border has another text.

The code, I tried:

```
.banner-text {
z-index:8;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 28px;
padding: 50px;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.banner-subtext {
z-index:9;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
margin-top: -25px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.banner-subtext::before {
}
```

Comment: Where's your code? What have you tried?

Comment: Added my code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use border on the main container but hide the bottom one. Then use pseudo element to complete the missing border:

```css
body {
 text-align:center;
 background:linear-gradient(to right, yellow, white);
}

.banner-text {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: none;
  position: relative;
}

.subtext {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.subtext:after,
.subtext:before {
  content: " ";
  height: 1px;
  background: #000;
  flex: 1;
}

.subtext:after {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.subtext:before {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-text">
  my text
  <div class="subtext">Sub text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This rectangle is most likely a vector graphic, stacked on top of the background image. The text is probably part of it, but it's possible the text is an additional div within the Image.

Another option is that the Larger text has a border set on the top, left and right and the subtext has a negative top margin along with ::before and ::after psuedo elements that have a border and width defined